# Unexpected white area below html in Reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I use Reactjs and encounter an unexpected white area below the html tag:

[image]

I've checked all my .css files and cannot find any margin, padding or position attributes that might cause that problem. When I use Google Chrome inspector, I cannot inspect that white space since it's below my html tag (image above). There's no error messages indicate the cause.

My react app structure:

[image]

Here's the code:

> App.js:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Wrapper from './components/Wrapper';
import SongCard from './components/SongCard';
import songs from './songs.json';

class App extends Component {
    state = {
        songs
    };

    render() {
        return ([
            <div key={0}>
                <Wrapper>
                    {this.state.songs.map(song => (
                        <SongCard
                            key={song.id}
                            id={song.id}
                            name={song.name}
                            artist={song.artist}
                            src={song.src}
                        />
                    ))}
                </Wrapper>
            </div>
        ]);
    }
}

export default App;
```

> Wrapper.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Wrapper.css';

const Wrapper = props => (
    <div className="row justify-content-center">
        <div className="col-lg-8">{props.children}</div>
    </div>
);

export default Wrapper;

Wrapper.css:
.row, .col-lg-8 {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Amaranth', sans-serif;
}
```

> SongCard.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './SongCard.css';

const SongCard = props => (
    <div className="song-card">
        <div className="row">
            <div className="col-auto spotify-player">
                <iframe title={props.id} src={props.src} frameBorder="0" allowtransparency="true"></iframe>
            </div>

            <div className="col text-center song-info">
                <div>{props.name}</div>
                <div>{props.artist}</div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div className="song-card-divider"></div>
    </div>
);

export default SongCard;
```

> SongCard.css:

```
iframe {
    width: 100%;
}

.col, .col-auto, .song-card {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #343a40;
}

.spotify-player {
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
}

.song-card-divider {
    height: 0;
    border-top: 1px solid #e9ecef;
}
```

I've looked for answers but couldn't find any answer.

Comment: This suggestion may sound silly, but have you tried close this tab and open again? Sometimes chrome developer tools gets buggy.

Comment: I have. I've also turned off the server and run yarn start again. The white area is still there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the cause of the problem:
It's the iframe height that causes the extra white area on the bottom of the page. I post my answer here so this question can be marked as answered and hopefully it helps people who have the same problem.